# REACT + GOOGLE-AUTH+ AWS-COGNITO , error while exchanging the authorization code to get session tokens

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito, google-signin, aws-amplify

I am using AWS Cognito and Google signup with React. I came up to the step where the authentication code appears at the top of the redirected_uri. Now, I am trying to send a post request to

```
https://<my_domain>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

to get the access and id tokens.

The code appeared on the search bar like: `http://localhost:3000/?code=e3090fba-d39c-4c8d-aaf9-4e82ebafcc70&state=BBCxKTIPx4QLwD17kOAhl0OyKo3f7g7O`

I used the below code in my home page to get the code from the URI and then send the post request to the above uri:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const exchangeCodeForTokens = async () => {
      try {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

        if (urlParams.has('code')) {
          const dcode = urlParams.get('code');
          const code = String(dcode)
          console.log(code)
        const tokenEndpoint = 'https://<my-domain>.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token';
        const clientId = <my-cognito-client-id>;
        const redirectUri = 'http://localhost:3000';

        const bodyParams = new URLSearchParams();
        bodyParams.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');
        bodyParams.append('client_id', clientId);
        bodyParams.append('code', code);
        bodyParams.append('redirect_uri', redirectUri);

        const response = await fetch(tokenEndpoint, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
          },
          body: bodyParams.toString(),
        });
        
        console.log(response)
        const data = await response.json();
        const accessToken = data.access_token;
        const idToken = data.id_token;
        const refreshToken = data.refresh_token;

        console.log(data,accessToken, idToken, refreshToken)

        console.log('Token exchange successful');
      }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };

    exchangeCodeForTokens();
  }, []);
```

I am getting the below error:

[image: Error while sending post request]

OAuth grant types in AWS-Cognito is set at Authorization code grant

My AWS-Amplify configuration:

```
Amplify.configure({
    Auth: {
        region: '*******',
        userPoolId: '***************',
        userPoolWebClientId: '**************',
        oauth : {
            domain: '<domain-name>.amazoncognito.com',
            redirectSignIn: 'http://localhost:3000',
            redirectSignOut: 'http://localhost:3000',
            scope : ['email', 'openid', 'profile', 'phone', 'aws.cognito.signin.user.admin'],
            responseType: 'code'
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: It would probably be super helpful for everyone if you logged the error here:

throw new Error('Failed to exchange code for tokens');

You'd probably be able to answer your last question.

Comment: You're likely missing the client secret.

Comment: I do not have the client secret in the aws-cognito, While creating the client , I did not opt for client secret.

Comment: @RobertMoskal , I have removed the throw error and printed the response and updated the image

Comment: Its working when I used the Hosted UI Signin link with my domain and redirected URI to get the authorization code at the top in the URL, but fails to work when using Auth.federatedSignin.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error and only managed to resolve it by using a Cognito app client that was created with a client secret. A pointer from AWS Token endpoint documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html)

> In a machine-to-machine model, your app sends a **client secret** to
> your token endpoint in exchange for access tokens.

In the same documentation, they do not give an example of using the token endpoint without the client secret.

Also, the error message you received, "invalid_request," typically occurs when the request is **missing a required parameter**, includes an unsupported parameter value (other than unsupported_grant_type), or is otherwise malformed.

Snippet of working code(I used axios for API calls)

```
  const params = {
    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
    client_id: global.clientId,
    redirect_uri: global.redirectUri,
    code: googleAuthID
  };

  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },
    auth: {
      username: global.clientId,
      password: global.clientSecret
    }
  };

  try {
    const response = await axios.post(
      `https://${global.domainPrefix}.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token`,
      querystring.stringify(params),
      config
    );

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      message: 'User successfully Logged In via Google',
      accessToken: response.data.access_token,
      token: response.data.id_token,
      expiresIn: response.data.expires_in
    };
```